# How I can get text enclosed inside custom tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get `Data1`,'Data2' and 'Data3' from the below text using JavaScript functions or regular expressions.

```
var myText= "<ls>  <data id="1">Data1</data> <data id="2">Data2</data> <data id="3">Data3</data> </ls>";
```

myText variable will hold the data as above, i need to extract Data 1 ,Data 2, and Data from it.

Comment: Have you tried parsing it as XML…?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Comment: To get the **Text** use `var ele = document.getElementById('1'); var text = ele.innerText || ele.textContent;` That is assuming `<data id="3">Data1</data>` is a typo and should read `<data id="3">Data3</data>`

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `document.getElementById`

```
document.getElementById('1').innerHTML
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rk57hkak/11/)

Comment: document.getElementById('1').innerHTML won't work. The string is in a variable.Need to extract Data1,Data2,Data3 from the string.

Comment: @Rocky can you share the problem

Comment: I guess you have edit the question. Originally it was not different

Comment: Hi the problem is , I got this string "<ls>  <data id="1">Data1</data> <data id="2">Data2</data> <data id="3">Data3</data> </ls>" and I want to extract Data1,Data2,Data3. I am using Javascript for Nodejs.